# SFINAE to detect static method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

I'm trying to implement a mechanism to detect whether provided class contains some static method or not. It's quite simple code but I cannot understand why `decltype()` doesn't work as expected for specialization of `EnableIfHasFooMethod` class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    static int Foo() { return 0; }
};

template <class T, class = void>
struct EnableIfHasFooMethod {};

template <class T>
struct EnableIfHasFooMethod<T, decltype(T::Foo)> {
    typedef void type;
};

template <class T, class = void>
struct HasFooMethod {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
struct HasFooMethod<T, typename EnableIfHasFooMethod<T>::type> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << HasFooMethod<A>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `0`, but should be `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to add `void()`

```
template <class T>
struct EnableIfHasFooMethod<T, decltype(T::Foo, void())> { /* ... */ };
// ...........................................^^^^^^^^
```

You need to match the second type (`void`) in

```
// ........................vvvv
template <class T, class = void>
struct EnableIfHasFooMethod {};
```

so your `decltype()` must return `void` iff (if and only if) there is a `Foo()` member in `T`.

You can't write

```
decltype( T::Foo )
```

because, in this case, `decltype()` return the type of the member `Foo` (if present) that can't be `void`.

You can't write

```
decltype( void() )
```

because, in this case, `decltype()` return **ever** `void`, but you want it iff there is a `Foo` member in `T`

So the solution is

```
decltype( T::Foo , void() )
```

so SFINAE can work, failing the substitution, if there isn't a `Foo` member and returning `void` if there is `Foo`.

Comment: I forgot that specialization should be for the default template parameters. Thank you!

Comment: just love the comma operator

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - so do I.

Comment: Or `void_t<decltype(T::Foo)>` , that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

As this may still interest people, let me remark that the `EnableIfHasFooMethod` is superfluous (if I am not mistaken). This should work just as well:

```c++
template <class T, class = void>
struct HasFooMethod: public std::false_type {};
template <class T>
struct HasFooMethod<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::Foo)>>: public std::true_type {};
```

Comment: But that won't distinguish between a static function `Foo()` and a member variable `Foo`.